# How do header and implementation files work in C++?

Tags: c++

I have a question about the relationship between header and implementation files in C++.

I have received two empty header files and one empty implementation file. When I say "empty" I mean that the files only contain method declarations; I have to implement the code inside each method. (I thought that posting the code for the three files would be redundant, since they only contain declarations..)

The three files are:

- `interface_complexmutex.h`
- `complexmutex.h`
- `complexmutex.cpp`

`interface_complexmutex.h` has **virtual** methods for `complexmutex`. Also, the `complexmutex` class inherits from `interface_complexmutex`.

These files have basic mutex functions that I have to implement. I have 2 questions:

1. Why do I need `interface_complexmutex.h`? It does not really have a `.cpp` file, and the entire implementation will be in `complexmutex` files, right?
2. How should I **include** these files and use `complexmutex` class in a program? (if I have the `init()` method in `complexmutex.cpp`, for example)

   Should `main.cpp` look like this?

   ```
   #include <stdlib.h>
   #include <stdio.h>
   #include "interface_complexmutex.h"
   #include "complexmutex.h"
   using namespace std;
   int main(){

       complexmutex a;

       /* do something with mutex to test */

       return 0;
   }
   ```

   I made my own Makefile, and the code above seems to run fine so far.

Comment: First, those aren't "library files"; those are header files. And one of them isn't even a header. Second, why does this sound suspiciously like homework?

Comment: @Nicol To address your second question, see [this recent discussion on Meta SO](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99013/is-it-ok-for-people-to-be-so-nagging-about-the-homework-tag/99017#99017).

Comment: Yes it is an assignment but I didn't really ask how to implement methods. I was questioning about how c++ works. I do not have much of c++ experience. I am sorry about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) You need an interface only if it is likely that the implementation will change later on. That will leave you free to make all the changes you want to the internals of your code without impacting the people using it to create software. That means that the users should *only* see the interface class and *never* the implementation.

To do that you'll need to implement what is called a `factory` pattern. This is a function that will create an instance of the implementation class and return it as a pointer (or reference) to the interface class. You probably can write that function as a static method of your interface class.

2) In a program you should image you are the user of your code. The user doesn't care how you implement your feature, so it should not use the implementation at all. If possible it should only include the interface header and call the factory method like this:

```
 #include "interface_complexmutex.h"
 using namespace std;

 int main(...) {
     interface_complemutex* mutex = interface_complexmutex::create_new(...);
     // do something interesting with the mutex
 }
```

In this example, `create_new` is your factory method. You can have parameters for it (usually an enumeration) if you have different implementations.

When using interfaces (actually abstract classes in C++), you need to use pointers or references. You can't create values for abstract classes. Of course, if you write test code, it's a bit different because test code is not meant to be seen/used by the users of your library.

Notes:

Let me point out that the naming is quite bad. The interface should be named `complexmutex` and the implementation `complexmutex_impl` since users should use the interface more, its name should be shorter (and you can replace the "impl" by something relevant such as "pthread" if you use pthreads to implement your mutex class.

As a PS note, in C++0x there is a thread library including mutex available. It is supported by some compilers already.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I just have one more question. How will `interface_complemutex* mutex` will know it will need to use functions declared in `complexmutex.h` file? Shouldn't I rather declare it like `interface_complexmutex* mutex = complexmutex::create_new(...);` ?? Because former one produces `cannot allocate an object of abstract type interface_complexmutex` error.

Comment: You must have `complexmutex` inherit from `complexmutex_interface` and in your factory method create an instance `complexmutex`. Since it's inheriting from the interface you can write (in the factory method) `complexmutex_interface* m = new complexmutex();` (this only works with pointers or references). THe user will be using a concrete object through its abstract interface. If one day you need to change and make an `another_complexmutex` class, you just need to change your factory, the code using complexmutex_interface will still work.

Comment: (Of course that supposes that `complexmutex_interface.h` includes `complexmutex.h`)

Answer (score 1):

Interfaces classes (C++ classes with all virtual functions) aid in reuse of interface design. These classes ideally capture only interface and not the implemenation. Hence they have only .h file and not corresponding .cpp file.

Coming to issue of re-use, suppose we need to define another mutex class, with completely different implemenation. We will not be able to re-use complexmutex class implementation but still be able to re-use interface_complexmutex class. Plus, objects of new mutex class can be used in place of complexmutex, as they have common interface.